# Bootstrap / initialization flow of AngularJS apps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, execution

I would like to know if the initialization flow of AngularJS apps is predictable in terms of the order of execution of different blocks within an HTML document.

I read this question [What is meant by Bootstrapping in angular JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058213/what-is-meant-by-bootstrapping-in-angular-js), which explains a lot of the process, but does not answer my question in detail.

I have a plunker example http://plnkr.co/edit/boVFjHWoxdbiADq41dXC?p=preview, where I console.log() numbers, in the order that I thought they would execute. What was a bit surprising though was that the execution of the .run() block seems to be deferred.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-rc.0" data-semver="1.4.0-rc.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <!--<script src="script.js"></script>-->

    <script>
      // Code goes here
      console.log(1);

      angular.module('app', [])
      .run(function () {
        console.log(2);
        setTimeout(function () {
          console.log(6);
        });
      });
    </script>

    <script>
      console.log(3);
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <img src="http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/Sicily-Italy.jpg" />

    <script>
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(5);
      })
    </script>

    <img src="http://www.wishsicily.com/gallery/1370_scicli-ragusa.jpg" />

    <script>
      console.log(4);
    </script>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

So I have a few questions:

1. Is it safe to say that the run() block, flagged in the console by the number "2", will always be executed after the rest of the page was processed?
2. I get that what initiates the execution of the .run() block is the call angularInit(), which is executed by the call ready() on DOM ready. Is that correct?
3. Does that mean that, in effect, the execution of the run() block happens on the same tick, as it would if it was assigned to window.onload?

Answer (score 1):

There is actually documentation about the run block on https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/ce669edfa14dc7eb7c389d2f82c9c98399a9009b/docs/content/guide/module.ngdoc

> ### Run Blocks
>
> Run blocks are the closest thing in Angular to the main method. A run
>   block is the code which needs to run to kickstart the application. It
>   is executed after all of the service have been configured and the
>   injector has been created. Run blocks typically contain code which is
>   hard to unit-test, and for this reason should be declared in isolated
>   modules, so that they can be ignored in the unit-tests.

The angularInit function initializes the modules which then call their own runblocks. That happens in src/angular.suffix

```
  jqLite(document).ready(function() {
    angularInit(document, bootstrap);
  });
```

So the run function will always be called after the document loaded.
Since Angular will start initializing then, there may be some time between the window.load and the initializing.